# How do I stop my aim from drifting?

Tags: technical-issues, ultrakill

While in game, my camera drifts up and to the right. This only happens when I am playing, as when I am in the menus or in the pause screen, it does not move in such a way (as well as that, my mouse does not move while it is not in the game).

How can I go about fixing this?

I play with Mouse and Keyboard, using a Razer Huntsman Mini Analog and a Razer Deathadder V2. I do not have any controllers connected to my computer.

Comment: Does it also happen with other mice? I understand you don't play with other controllers but it would be useful to test if other hardware has the same issue.

Comment: I will try it with some spare mice I have around and a spare keyboard if I have one sitting around.